# How to automatically transfer ETH from my address to another

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3j, address.transfer

I want to format or configure my ETH wallet in a way that if any ETH comes into the address, it will automatically be sent to another address.

I have the feeling that my private key is being compromised, and I used the address as payment address for a website and I can't easily change to another address, so I need a way to automate any payment that comes in to that wallet to another address fast.

I've googled to the ends of the earth and haven't seen any tutorial on this. I saw something about using web3js to watch address and forward any incoming eth fast to another address as soon as it enters with a script, but the person didn't say how to do this.

Comment: If you private key is compromised, the only thing you should be thinking about is how to change your wallet to a new address with a new private key. There is no process you can set up such that someone wont be able to do it faster than you.

Comment: Shawn Tabrizi, I'm sure there must be. Like using web3js to watch my address and using a script to forward any eth in my account to my new address. The script will have a set gas limit, use a quarter of the received amount as transaction fee to send the rest to my account. I know there is a way to do this, I've seen it online, but haven't seen a tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: Yes you CAN do it, but if your account is compromised then it would be very unwise to ignore that fact.

Comment: Shawn Tabrizi, yes I know and aware of the impending risks, but please I need to know how to do it. What's the script and how do I insert the script in my wallet and let it run. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question, which I had a script that might be of interest https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46006/20451

Comment: Omg! Linmao Song you're God sent! Exactly what I was looking for. Please can you tell me how to edit the script and run it using infura and nodejs?