# Script to transfer tokens automatically based on time

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

How can I create a simple script which calls a transfer function every 5 hours instead of me having to manually click it every 5 hours?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but relatively easy to modify this script to make it run in intervals https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46006/20451

Answer (score 1):

You can create one via `node.js` and `web3`.

Import the contract ABI and the address and also import your wallet account (don't share your private keys with others!). Now you can call the transfer() function every 5 hours.

Comment: Would you be able to provide me a dummy template/example to study?